# Swift timer in background

Tags: ios, swift, timer, background

I create a background task in iOS by trigger from a geofence. In this background I start a timer to count down time to timeout this task. However, this timer work incorrectly, maybe pause after 10s and resume whenever I bing my app to foreground.

I need help to make this timer work correctly in 10 minute.
This is my code

```
@objc func timeoutChecking(_ timer: Timer) {
    print("time \(self.currentTime)")
    if self.currentTime != TIME_SEARCH {
        self.currentTime += 1
    }
    else {
        // Time out
        self.stopChecking()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's happened because you fire your timer in `main` thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to run timer continuously in the background after a couple seconds apple may discard the timer.

You can do one thing, take one global variable add set current time in `applicationDidEnterBackground`, and `applicationWillEnterForeground` check in this method take current system time and stored previous time compare both times and get a difference between them and check is,

```
if self.currentTime != TIME_SEARCH {
        self.currentTime += 1
    }
    else {
        // Time out
        self.stopChecking()
}
```

You have to check here like  `if self.currentTime > TIME_SEARCH` or `if self.currentTime < TIME_SEARCH` so you can get perfect result. :)